# How to create multiple variables from single variables output in PHP or smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

The php code.

```
    public function GetProduct($id, $bc = '')
{
    $productname = WHMCS\Product\Product::getProductName($id);
    $description = WHMCS\Product\Product::getProductDescription($id);
    $details = WHMCS\Product\Product::find($id);
    $pricing = $details->pricing();
    if ($bc == '') {
        $price = $pricing->first();
    } else {
        $price = $pricing->byCycle($bc);
        if (is_null($price)) {
            $price = $pricing->first();
        }
    }
    return array(
        'name' => $productname,
        'description' => $description,
        'price' => $price,
    );
}
```

Output when i am using {$description} variable in tpl file.

```
Disk Space: 1000 MB
Bandwidth: 10,000 MB
Email Accounts: 25
Subdomains: 100
MySql DataBase: UNLIMITED

This is test information for products
```

[Screenshot from phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGShG.png)

I want create multiple variables from this output to get below result so i can use like below 3 variables in tpl file.

```
$feature =  Disk Space
$value = 100 MB 

etc..

and also 
$feature.description = This is test information for products.
```

If this is an unclear question, let me know and I will attempt to clear it up.

Thanks

Comment: If the format is always the same, you can pull out the info using regex

Comment: could you please help me? how and which tags.

Comment: Will the description always have those same five lines? Disks Space: value? Do the headings change?

Comment: Yes, i am getting same format like Disks Space: 100 MB, I want split in to two variables like {feature} and {value} as well as last single line has blank space so want use third one a {desc}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the result string is same as in your question you can simply separate them by new line and then explode by `:`. here is code.

```
$str = 'Disk Space: 1000 MB
Bandwidth: 10,000 MB
Email Accounts: 25
Subdomains: 100
MySql DataBase: UNLIMITED';

$arr = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $str);
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$a){
    $temp = explode(':', $a);
    $new[$key]['feature'] = trim($temp[0]);
    $new[$key]['value'] = trim($temp[1]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '<br>';
print_r($new);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Disk Space: 1000 MB
    [1] => Bandwidth: 10,000 MB
    [2] => Email Accounts: 25
    [3] => Subdomains: 100
    [4] => MySql DataBase: UNLIMITED
)

Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [feature] => Disk Space
        [value] => 1000 MB
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [feature] => Bandwidth
        [value] => 10,000 MB
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [feature] => Email Accounts
        [value] => 25
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [feature] => Subdomains
        [value] => 100
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [feature] => MySql DataBase
        [value] => UNLIMITED
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be done cleaner but it'll get the job done:

```
$description = "Disk Space: 1000 MB
Bandwidth: 10,000 MB
Email Accounts: 25
Subdomains: 100
MySql DataBase: UNLIMITED

This is test information for products,
with a multiline description";

$descArr = explode("\r\n", $description);
$lineCount = 1;
$desc = "";
foreach ($descArr as $line)
{
    if ($lineCount <= 5)
    {
        list($key, $val) = explode(":", $line);
        $val = trim($val);
        echo "key: [" . $key . "] \n";
        echo "val: [" . $val . "] \n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $desc .= $line . "\n";
    }
    $lineCount++;
}

echo "desc:" . $desc . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
key: [Disk Space]
val: [1000 MB]

key: [Bandwidth]
val: [10,000 MB]

key: [Email Accounts]
val: [25]

key: [Subdomains]
val: [100]

key: [MySql DataBase]
val: [UNLIMITED]

desc:
This is test information for products,
with a multiline description
```

I just `echo`d out the pairs of key/value. You can store them into variables if you want of course.

---

If you want the key/val pair stored in variables:

```
$description = "Disk Space: 1000 MB
Bandwidth: 10,000 MB
Email Accounts: 25
Subdomains: 100
MySql DataBase: UNLIMITED

This is test information for products,
with a multiline description";

$descArr = explode("\r\n", $description);

$keys = $vals = [];
$lineCount = 0;
$desc = "";

foreach ($descArr as $line)
{
    if ($lineCount < 5)
    {
        list($key, $val) = explode(":", $line);
        $val = trim($val);
        $keys[$lineCount] = $key;
        $vals[$lineCount] = $val;
    }
    else
    {
        $desc .= $line . "\n";
    }
    $lineCount++;
}

var_dump($keys); 
var_dump($vals); 
echo "desc:" . $desc . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Disk Space"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "Bandwidth"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "Email Accounts"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "Subdomains"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "MySql DataBase"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "1000 MB"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "10,000 MB"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "100"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "UNLIMITED"
}
desc:
This is test information for products,
with a multiline description
```

`$keys` & `$vals` are parallel arrays. This all is based on the format of five lines at the top of `$description` with `key`:`value` being the format.